# ¿Cómo deshabilitar una lista de checkbox e inputs extraidos de una BD con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, laravel

En mi BD tengo dos tablas llamadas 'producto' y 'material', estoy haciendo un CRUD para los productos y en la vista 'create' extraigo la lista de materiales registrados en la BD con la finalidad de seleccionar la cantidad de materiales que se usaron en la elaboración de un producto.

A continuación se muestra una tabla la cual contiene una lista de checkbox con los materiales, y un input de tipo number el cual registrará la cantidad de material utilizado:

```
 <table class="table">

    @foreach($material as $mat)
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 50%">
<input type="checkbox" id="boxMat" name="mat[]" value="{{$mat['id']}}">{{$mat['nombre']}}
   </td>

     <td style="width: 25%">
        <input class="input-group-text" id="unidadM" type="number" name="unidadM[]" min="0" >
    </td>
    <td style="width: 25%">
       {{$mat['unidad']}}
    </td>
    </tr>

    @endforeach
   </table>
```

y el siguiente código en JavaScript

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName("unidadM[]").length; i++) {

  document.getElementByName('mat[]')[i].onchange = function() {
    document.getElementByName('unidadM[]')[i].disabled = !this.checked;
  }

}
```

Lo que quiero es que al momento de cargar la vista 'create' los input que se encuentran al lado de lista de checkbox estén deshabilitados, y se habiliten sólo si se selecciona el checkbox correspondiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que cuando crees los inputs dentro de un bucle le asignes un incremental a el `id` por ejemplo `id="boxMat1"`, `id="boxMat2"`, etc., Ya que el id debe de ser único, mencionado esto te explico el código, obtenemos las etiquetas de los checkbox (eso ya lo tienes claro), así mismo las recorremos con un `for`, después por medio del `id` le agregamos un `.addEventListener` de tipo `change`, obtenemos el `id` del checbox seleccionado y le hacemos un `split()` para obtener sólo el número (aunque puedes agregar atributos `data-*` para no ocuparlo), guardamos en una variable `idNum`  la posición `[1]` que sería el número que requerimos, después validamos si el check esta `checked` habilitamos el input tipo `number` -> `document.getElementById(`num${idNum}`).disabled = false;`  y si no esta checado lo des-habilitamos. Espero sea lo que requieres, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
var check = document.getElementsByName('mat[]');

for(var i = 0; i < check.length; i++){
    let checks = check[i].id;
    
   document.getElementById(checks).addEventListener('change',function(){
    
    let idCheck = this.id.split('check');
      
      let idNum = idCheck[1];
      
      console.log(idNum);
      
      if(this.checked){
        document.getElementById(`num${idNum}`).disabled = false;
        
      }else{
      
        document.getElementById(`num${idNum}`).disabled = true;
      
      }
    
    
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="mat[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="mat[]" value="2">

<input type="number" id="num1" name="unidadM[]" disabled>
<input type="number" id="num2" name="unidadM[]" disabled>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, funcionó perfectamente

Comment: Me alegro, excelente día compañero. :)